# How can I include svg / png / vml images directly in an xls sheet?

Tags: image, excel, svg, xls

I want to include (if I even can) directly an `svg` image into an xls sheet that is written in xml like

```
<Worksheet><Row><Cell></Cell></Row></Worksheet>
```

I want to embed them directly but I don't know how I can do this in `xml` and what works in excel 2003.

Or doesnt it even work with ms excel? I need to show an `svg` image directly in an excel sheet.

Comment: I don't think that format supports embedded images.

Comment: hm seems i cant use svg in excel 2003 / 2007?

Comment: xls was the default format in excel until 2003. Now days it's xlsx. Maybe you'll have better luck there